# DIV doesn't right align when containing another div with min and max widths

Tags: css, sass

So I have a layout that contains 3 column divs inside a row div.  Inside the first first column div, I have another div with min-width, max-width associated with it.

When I try to `text-align: center;` the first column div, the alignment never happens?

https://jsfiddle.net/0mp4zyje/

```css
.container {}

.icon-col {
  text-align: right;
}

.col-25 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.icon {
  width: 38px;
  min-width: 38px;
  max-width: 38px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-25 icon-col">
    <div class="icon">I</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50">
    this is 50%
  </div>
  <div class="col-25">
    25%
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of min/max height when they're the same value?

Comment: Also, it's a little unclear if you're trying to align right or centre.  The title and fiddle say align right, the text says `align: center;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `div` is a block element, not an inline element.  To solve the problem, add `display:inline-block` on the `.icon` div.

```
.icon {
    width: 38px;
    min-width: 38px;
    max-width: 38px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.container {
}

.icon-col {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-25 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.col-50 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.icon {
    width: 38px;
    min-width: 38px;
    max-width: 38px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-25 icon-col">
        <div class="icon">I</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-50">
        this is 50%
    </div>
    <div class="col-25">
        25%
    </div>
</div>
```

- Aligned center: https://jsfiddle.net/0mp4zyje/2/
- Aligned right: https://jsfiddle.net/0mp4zyje/3/

Comment: FWIW, I'd use an inline element, like `<span>` or `<i>`.

Comment: I agree - I'm not sure why they used a `<div>` in the first place.

Comment: Worked. Thanks.  @Jonathan this is a majorly condensed version of the real code.  There are multiple elements in the <div> above that contains the "I" in the real code.

Answer (score 1):

The object isn't expanding because it has no reason to; the content is at a width below the `max-width`.

To center this content, you just need to add a `margin: 0 auto` to your `icon`.

https://jsfiddle.net/0mp4zyje/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.icon {
  width: 38px; /* Fixed width div*/
  min-width: 38px;
  max-width: 38px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin: auto; /* This will place the div center to its parent */
  text-align:center;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
}
```

Please check the modified line of your CSS code above. When you use fixed width to your `<div>` element (i.e what your are doing), make sure you use margin:auto; to make it horizontally center.